# Fade element out and fade in data from Array - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have 4 `div` items on my page, I'm trying to get the inner html of these items to fade out randomly, take a row from an array and fade that in - in its place, does this make sense?

```
// My items that I would like to repopulate the faded out info

var testimonialsArray = [
    "<div class='change'><h1>Box 5</h1><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>", 
    "<div class='change'><h1>Box 6</h1><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>", 
    "<div class='change'><h1>Box 7</h1><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>", 
    "<div class='change'><h1>Box 8</h1><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>", 
    "<div class='change'><h1>Box 9</h1><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>" 
];

// Find a random div and fade it out

var order = Math.floor((Math.random()* $('.change').length )+1);

$('.box').eq(order).find('.change').fadeOut();

.......Fade in new data from an array row
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crn7dysu/1/

Comment: This code never generates 0 as index

Comment: So, aside from the 0 index problem, *what* is your actual problem? You do not actually say what is not working the way you want.

Comment: You mean something like: $('.box').fadeOut(500).html( getRandomDiv() ).fadeIn(500);  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I think you wanted to do:

```
var order = Math.floor((Math.random()* $('.change').length ));

$('.box').eq(order).find('.change').fadeOut(function(){
   $(this).html(testimonialsArray[Math.floor((Math.random()* testimonialsArray.length))]).fadeIn();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/crn7dysu/4/

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you get 0 from `Math.random()` and that `$('.change').length` is 10

```
Math.floor((0 * 10) + 1);
```

You can see that this code will never generate 0 as output.

This one instead will generate all the possible combinations:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()* $('.change').length);
```

Comment: The `+1` was certainly wrong, but `length-1` is also incorrect as `Math.random` returns `"up to but not including 1 (exclusive)"` so never hits the `length` value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this script:

```
var testimonialsArray = [
    "<div class='change'><h1>Box 5</h1><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>", 
    "<div class='change'><h1>Box 6</h1><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>", 
    "<div class='change'><h1>Box 7</h1><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>", 
    "<div class='change'><h1>Box 8</h1><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>", 
    "<div class='change'><h1>Box 9</h1><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>" 
];

var order = Math.floor((Math.random()* $('.box').length )+1);
var newOrder = Math.floor((Math.random()* testimonialsArray.length ));

$('.box:nth-child('+order+')').find(".change").fadeOut( function() {
    $(testimonialsArray[newOrder]).appendTo('.box:nth-child('+order+')').hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/crn7dysu/5/)

Comment: Constructing a string selector, just to use `:nth-child`, seems a little wasteful don't you think? The original code was shorter/faster (but just had an incorrect `+1` index).